# PHP 404 Error Not Redirecting

Tags: php, .htaccess

So while editing my .HTACCESS file I added the proper lines to redirect users that encounter errors like 404 and 500. It works like a charm if I tell it to display a specific message. However if I tell the file to redirect users to a custom error page it fails.
When testing out my 404 redirect I get this:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /143/test.php was not found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80
```

As you can see it is stating that my ErrorDocument is not found BUT if I type my ErrorDocument URL in I can go to it myself.
My .HTACCESS file looks like this:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /error.php
ErrorDocument 401 /error.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php
ErrorDocument 502 /error.php
ErrorDocument 504 /error.php

php_flag display_startup_errors off
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag html_errors off
# enable PHP error logging
php_flag log_errors on
php_value error_log PHP_errors.log
```

NOTE: I am using localhost (WAMP).
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were looking for a file called `"/143/test.php"`, but (usually) yout `.htaccess` goes in the web root. `.htaccess` is looking for `error.php` in the `/143` directory, so put a copy of it there or use an absolute URL in your `.htaccess`

Comment: Understood. After changing /error.php to /143/error.php it worked just fine. I didn't understand that .htaccess looked at the root folder like that. Thank you :)